# Can this change in code cause a serious memory leak?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks

Because we need to call the code below from VB6 we had to change the signature of the method from

`int STDCALL CalcDDtable(struct ddTableDeal  tableDeal, struct ddTableResults * tablep`

to

`int STDCALL CalcDDtable(struct ddTableDeal * tableDeal, struct ddTableResults * tablep`

The ddTableDeal struct contains just an array of 16 bytes and the ddTableResults struct contains just one array of 20 bytes and is filled with the results of the dll's calculation.

The code is called from VB6 thus:

```
Declare Function CalcDDtable Lib "dds222vb6.dll" (ByRef lngDeal As Long, ByRef lngResult As Long) As Long
Dim Cards(15) As Long   
Dim Results(19) As Long
'Some code to populate the Cards array. The Results arrays contains zeroes.
lngErrorCode = CalcDDtable(Cards(0), Results(0))
```

However, the testing computer freezes with an Out Of Memory Exception after 150,000 iterations. Can this be caused by the change in signature? To us it seems unlikely as 150,000 times 36 bytes amounts to just over 5MB of memory.

The full (adjusted) code. The only changes are in the signature and in that `ddTableDeal.cards` has been changed in `ddTableDeal->cards`.

```
int STDCALL CalcDDtable(struct ddTableDeal * tableDeal, struct ddTableResults * tablep) {

  int h, s, k, ind, tr, first, res;
  struct deal dl;
  struct boards bo;
  struct solvedBoards solved;

  for (h=0; h<=3; h++)
    for (s=0; s<=3; s++)
      dl.remainCards[h][s]=tableDeal->cards[h][s];

  for (k=0; k<=2; k++) {
    dl.currentTrickRank[k]=0;
    dl.currentTrickSuit[k]=0;
  }

  ind=0; bo.noOfBoards=20;

  for (tr=4; tr>=0; tr--) 
    for (first=0; first<=3; first++) {
      dl.first=first;
      dl.trump=tr;
      bo.deals[ind]=dl;
      bo.target[ind]=-1;
      bo.solutions[ind]=1;
      bo.mode[ind]=1;
      ind++;
    }

  res=SolveAllBoards4(&bo, &solved);
  if (res==1) {
    for (ind=0; ind<20; ind++) {
      tablep->resTable[bo.deals[ind].trump][rho[bo.deals[ind].first]]=
        13-solved.solvedBoard[ind].score[0];
    }
    return 1;
  }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to show the code that's *calling* this function.

Comment: this is tagged as C++ but looks like C to me

Comment: Or to produce a minimal example containing *only* the behaviour that you don't understand, without any additional complexity.

Comment: What's happening on SolveAllBoards4?

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't allocate or free any memory at all. So *by itself* it cannot be a memory leak. But the redesign you've made could be causing a memory leak, it all depends on how you are using `CalcDDtable`.

Comment: @Amber I added the calling code.

Comment: @john I added the calling code

Comment: @Nick If you are interested in the full source it is available at http://privat.bahnhof.se/wb758135/ If I know that the minimal change I made is not responsible for the problem I will contact the author.

Comment: @Dabblernl OK calling C++ from VB is another matter. Whether this is a memory leak or not is not something I have any clue about. You're likely to get better advice in a VB forum I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function signature of CalcDDtable doesn't leak memory.  The code in function CalcDDtable has some local variables that get allocated on the stack when the function is called and get popped off the stack when the function returns.  So your memory leak is not in this function.